# Iterate through C# list looking for multiple matching strings and return index positions

Tags: c#

I want to iterate through a list of strings and return the matching strings as well as the index values. My code works for getting a single match but not for multiple matches. For example when I input "David" as the responseName the output tells me that there is a match at index 0 twice. I was expecting it to return a match at index 0 and index 3. My guess is that the index variable isn't reset for each iteration.

```
List<string> studentNames = new List<string>() { "David", "Steve", "Bob", "David", "Ryan" };
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a name to check if there is a match in the database.");
            string responseName = Console.ReadLine();
            bool nameGuess = false;
            foreach (string name in studentNames)
            {
                int index = studentNames.IndexOf(name);
                if (name == responseName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is at least 1 match with the following name: " + name);
                    nameGuess = true;
                    index = studentNames.IndexOf(name);
                    if (index != -1)
                        Console.WriteLine("The name \"{0}\" had a match at index {1}", name, index);
                    
                }  
            }
            if (nameGuess == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There were no matches for that name.");
            }
```

Comment: You should be able to use Linq with Where and this [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because
`int index = studentNames.IndexOf(name);`
will always return the first occurrence of your list, which is not what you want

What you want is to loop through all the items in your list and display their respective index, so instead, you should be using a for loop instead of a foreach loop or you will not be able to capture the index

```
        List<string> studentNames = new List<string>() { "David", "Steve", "Bob", "David", "Ryan" };
        Console.WriteLine("Please input a name to check if there is a match in the database.");
        string responseName = Console.ReadLine();
        bool nameGuess = false;
        for(int index = 0; index<studentNames.Count; index++)
        {
            string name = studentNames[index];
           
            if (name == responseName)
            {
                nameGuess = true;
                //index = studentNames.IndexOf(name);
                //if (index != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("The name \"{0}\" had a match at index {1}", name, index);
                break;
            }  
        }
        if (nameGuess == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There were no matches for that name.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is at least 1 match with the following name: " + responseName);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach using Linq:

```
List<string> studentNames = new List<string>() { "David", "Steve", "Bob", "David", "Ryan" };
Console.WriteLine("Please input a name to check if there is a match in the database.");
string responseName = Console.ReadLine();

var matchingIndices = studentNames
    .Select((x, i) => new {Name = x, Index =i}) //project the index into the resultset
    .Where(x => x.Name == responseName) //filter
    .Select(x => x.Index); //select only the index

foreach(var index in matchingIndices)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```